# Flickering when the dynamic change width

Tags: javascript, css

I want to dynamically change the width of an element. I've got working code, but it's sometimes flickering. Any idea, why?

JS:

```
 var counter = 0;
 setInterval(function() {
   counter = (counter + 1) % 100;
   $(".xxx").css("width", counter + "%");
 }, 40);
```

CSS:

```
 .xxx {
     max-width: 70px; 
     height: 3px;
     width: 0%; 
     background-color: orange; 
 }
```

Comment: What did you mean with flickering? That it restart again?

Comment: I see two things that might be what you're describing as flickering. First, you set the max-width to 70, so the width will "pause" at 70px if 100% width is more than that. If it's because the width jumps from 100% to 0, then you need to adjust the code to reverse the counter instead of doing modulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how it is going to look if you try to increment 1% at a time. Rather use jquery animate to get better transition

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/8OsVuRJGCLQsJWfrlzJ4

```
var counter =0;
    setInterval(function() {
      counter = (counter + 1) % 100;
      $(".xxx").animate({width:counter+'px'});
   }, 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reach a 70px width when it gets to 100%, you need to add a div parent to .xxx

like this:

```
<div class="yyy">
    <div class="xxx"></div>
</div>

<p id="text"></p>
```

css:

```
.xxx{
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%; 
    background-color: orange; 
}

.yyy{
    width: 70px;
}
```